# How to compare database fields in FeathersJS

Tags: feathersjs

I need to find all records where `columnA <= columnB`. I don't see any mention of this feature in [the documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/databases/querying.html).

Is it possible? How?

Comment: This is not part of the common querying syntax and depends on the database you are using. The functionality itself can be implemented by [extending the adapter](https://docs.feathersjs.com/databases/extending.html).

Comment: Hi, @Daff. I'm using feathers-sequelize. Do you know whether it offers that functionality out-of-the-box or not? If not, do you know why? I think I'll use Sequelize directly for this query, but it would be cleaner if I could use Feathers like I've done in most other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Sequelize, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452977/sequelize-query-compare-dates-in-two-columns) you should be able to accomplish this using `sequelize.col`. This condition can be added as a `before` `find` hook like this:

```
app.service('users').before({
  find(hook) {
    const { query } = hook.params;

    query.columnA = { $gte: sequelize.col('columnB') };
  }
});
```

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense :)