# Mimic where [condition] between [colA] and [colB] sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Looking for assistance in replicating the following mssql operation in sequelize. We have a table with a valid_from and valid_to columns and I need to get todays current date and only return the records that are fall based on that.

I am looking to utilize the .findByPK(), or  .findAll() methods in sequelize

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN f.valid_from AND f.valid_to
```

I have found the following posts and items with no luck. As they seem to specify two di9ffernt dates between the same column. I need to compare the current UTCDATE between two different columns

[Sequelize Query to find all records that falls in between date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115151/sequelize-query-to-find-all-records-that-falls-in-between-date-range)

[Sequelize query - compare dates in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452977/sequelize-query-compare-dates-in-two-columns)

I was able to simulate but would still like to know if anyone knows how to do the same thing using the `between` operator

```
const now = new Date();
            return await models.Form.findAll({
                where: {
                    valid_from: {
                        [Op.lte]: Sequelize.cast(now, 'DATETIMEOFFSET')
                    },
                    [Op.and]: {
                        validTo: {
                            [Op.gte]: Sequelize.cast(now, 'DATETIMEOFFSET')
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: So what is wrong with the query you show here?

Comment: Its using raw sql and I wand to use model.findAll()

Comment: Yes, but you said you "found the following posts" but don't say why they didn't work either.

Comment: updated the post, but in short all the examples I have found are comparing different dates between a single column, I need to get the current UTCDate and compare between two different columns

Comment: How about? I dont know what sequelize.js is but I know sql server

SELECT * FROM [table] AS F WHERE F.valid_from >= GETUTCDATE() AND F.valid_to <= GETUTCDATE()

Comment: thanks for the attempt but I am really trying to use the orm (sequllize)

Comment: Just a note that you don't need `Op.and` in your example query, it is the default, so you can have `valid_from` and `validTo` on the same level to do an `AND`, however the answer for using `BETWEEN` is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this query using `sequelize.where()` to generate the WHERE statement for the BETWEEN operation. For the current timestamp you need to call `GETUTCDATE()` which we can do via `sequelize.fn()`.

```js
const forms = await models.Form.findAll({
  where: {
    // create where condition for GETUTCDATE()
    sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('GETUTCDATE'), {
      // BETWEEN valid_from AND validTo
      [Op.between]: [
        sequelize.col('valid_from'), 
        sequelize.col('validTo')
      ],
    }),
  },
});
```

This will generate SQL like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `form`
WHERE GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN `valid_from` AND `validTo`
```

> *note that you have underscored `valid_from` and camelCase `validTo` in your example.*

Comment: yeah that was a bad thing in my comment they are both camelCase in real life, thanks for the example